# How to Reference ruby code Inside a JS alert tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, alert

I'm new to JS and was wondering if someone could help me figure this alert out?

```
<% if @candy.errors %>
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
      alert('<%= @candy.errors.full_messages %>')
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This is all that comes up on the alert: []

Comment: What does it show when you log it out, does anthing different show if you add `.to_json` to it? So, `@candy.errors.full_messages.to_json`

Comment: also try `@candy.errors.inspect` to see what the structure you are getting is

Comment: I think the `.inspect` might work if I can figure out a different place in my form to put it. It at least displayed everything if in the wrong form.  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: What error are you expecting?  If you print out `<%= @candy.errors.count %>` do you get a number shown?

Comment: Also, the point of adding those methods was to show what information was being presented in that object.  So, just to be clear, there was nothing returned when you added `.inspect` or nothing shown when you added `.to_json` that gave any further indication of what is being included on the `@candy.errors` ?

Comment: #&lt;ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f911ee823b0 @base=#&lt;Candy id: nil, name: nil, sweetness: nil, yummy: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, img_url: nil, description: nil&gt;, @messages={}, @details={}&gt;

Answer (score 0):

`<% if @candy.errors %>` will always return a truthy value. The value it returns is an instance of `ActiveModel::Errors`. By truthy, I mean it will never return false or nil, and therefore your alert will always show...even if there are no errors with @candy.

You'll need to add `.any?` to return false if there are no errors.

```
<% if @candy.errors.any? %>
```

If my assumption that there are no errors with the `@candy` you are working with is correct, no alert should show when any? is added.

To manually add an error to @candy, add this line before `<% if @candy.errors.any? %>`...

```
<% @candy.errors.add :base, "Test" %>
```

If an alert pops up then the issue is simply that `@candy` has no errors and your call to `@candy.errors.full_messages` correctly returns an empty array.